# Selecting rows from pandas DataFrame using two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in pandas that I'd like to select a subset of rows from based on the values of two columns.

```
test_df = DataFrame({'Topic' : ['A','A','A','B','B'], 'Characteristic' : ['Population','Other','Other','Other','Other'], 'Total' : [25, 22, 21, 20, 30]})
```

It works as expected and returns the first row when I use this code:

```
bool1 = test_df['Topic']=='A' 
bool2 = test_df['Characteristic']=='Population'

test_df[bool1 & bool2]
```

But when I try to do it all in one line as below,

```
test_df[test_df['Topic']=='A' & test_df['Characteristic']=='Population']
```

I get "TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]"

Why?  Is there a good way to do this in a single step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to add parentheses:

```
>>> test_df[(test_df['Topic']=='A') & (test_df['Characteristic']=='Population')]
  Characteristic Topic  Total
0     Population     A     25
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method, to avoid the repetition of `test_df`:

```
>>> test_df.query("Topic == 'A' and Characteristic == 'Population'")
  Characteristic Topic  Total
0     Population     A     25
```

Comment: I'm glad you included the query example. While it's 'only' syntactic sugar, it makes code *much* more readable.