# select rows in pandas DataFrame using comparisons against two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1, 2, 3, 4] ,'two' : [5, 6, 7, 8]})
   one  two
0    1    5
1    2    6
2    3    7
3    4    8
```

Column "one" and column "two" together comprise (x,y) coordinates

Lets say I have a list of coordinates: `c =  [(1,5), (2,6), (20,5)]`

Is there an elegant way of obtaining the rows in `df`
with matching coordinates? In this case, given `c`, the matching rows would be 0 and 1

Related question: [Using pandas to select rows using two different columns from dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937022/using-pandas-to-select-rows-using-two-different-columns-from-dataframe?rq=1)

And: [Selecting rows from pandas DataFrame using two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110224/selecting-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-using-two-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
>>> set.union(*(set(df.index[(df.one == i) & (df.two == j)]) for i, j in c))
{0, 1}
```

Comment: This looks to be horribly slow, I wish it wasn't marked as the correct answer.  See the `merge` answer.

Answer (score 1):

This approaching using `pd.merge` should perform better than the iterative solutions.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"one" : [1, 2, 3, 4] ,"two" : [5, 6, 7, 8]})
c = [(1, 5), (2, 6), (20, 5)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=["one", "two"])

pd.merge(df, df2, on=["one", "two"], how="inner")
   one  two
0    1    5
1    2    6
```